# Codeigniter routes working with url indexes

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to rewrite the indexes of an url with the routes ?

```
$route['name-(:num)'] = name/name2?index1=$1;
```

And it isn't working.

```
$route['name-(:num)'] = name/name2/?index1=$1;
```

This is returned wrong sql query, becouse the index is not defined .

How to get the indexes ?

Answer (score 0):

Not personally a 100% sure on how CodeIgniter url rewriting works, but if they use .htaccess to map all requests to a single PHP file you can't use regular $_GET variables via "?" anymore, you have to route them.